# MySql - Update first empty column found

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have a table in Mysql that looks like this:

```
Name    Slot_1  Slot_2  Slot_3
------  ------  ------  --------
MyName  MyItem                  
MyName2
```

And I have this app with an interface to buy some products. When the client "MyName" buy something in the app, it would store it on "Slot_2" because "Slot_1" is already used; On the other hand, if MyName2 buys the same product, it would be stored on Slot_1 because it's the first free slot found. I searched through several links, but all I found was how to update the first empty row found, and not the column.

Note: The app is made in VB.net, so if you think it would be better to do this app-level, feel free to comment.
Note 2: This is the best db-design I found to do this "inventory". If you think there is a better way to do it, please point me to it.

Comment: And when the customer buys the 4th product?

Comment: It is intended to have a limit.

Comment: is there only 3 slots or there can be more ?

Comment: There are actually 30 slots, but as I said, it is intended to have a limit. The app wouldn't even try to add new items if all slots are taken.

Comment: I mean this with all good intentions: You might want to redesign your database schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is really a bad design. I really suggest to read something basic on building relational databases.

Said that the only correct approach is to have at least three tables

The first table contains the customer informations

```
IDCustomer Name    Address City   
---------- ------  ------  --------
1          Steve   XXXX    YYYY 
2          Andre   KKKK    ZZZZ
```

The second table contains the Items that can be sold

```
IDItem     Item    Price   
---------- ------  ------  
1          Apple   1    
2          Orange  2
```

The third table links the Customers with the Items sold

```
IDItem     IDCustomer    Quantity
-------    -----------   ---------
1          1             5
2          2             10
1          2             3
```

Also if you want to limit the items sold to a customer to only three, that is a business rule that should not be enforced by a database design like that.

Comment: Oh sorry, I should have included that info in the first post. I already have a table for items that can be sold and a table with users info. The third table would contain the items bought by each user. Doing the third table the way you said would work great I think, I'll give it a try and see.

Comment: All right then, just use the schema like the third one then. Really avoid that SlotXXX mess and apply something in your code to enforce the limits. How do you plan to search for products sold with a product that can appear in any column?

Comment: Like this of course: `WHERE ([Slot_1] = @ITEM OR [Slot_2] = @ITEM OR [Slot_3] = @ITEM OR [Slot_4] = @ITEM OR [Slot_5] = @ITEM OR [Slot_6] = @ITEM OR [Slot_7] = @ITEM OR [Slot_8] = @ITEM OR [Slot_9] = @ITEM OR [Slot_10] = @ITEM OR [Slot_11] = @ITEM OR [Slot_12] = @ITEM OR [Slot_13] = @ITEM OR [Slot_14] = @ITEM OR [Slot_15] = @ITEM OR [Slot_16] = @ITEM OR [Slot_17] = @ITEM OR [Slot_18] = @ITEM OR [Slot_19] = @ITEM OR [Slot_20] = @ITEM OR [Slot_21] = @ITEM OR [Slot_22] = @ITEM OR [Slot_23] = @ITEM OR [Slot_24] = @IT ..` I think this is pretty self explainable why you should use @Steve's approach.

Comment: Doing this way worked great for me, thanks @Steve!
It was right under my nose all the time and I didn't see it. Even invited some friends on TS but we couldn't think of something better than the "SlotXXX mess" as you say :p Guess we were really tunnel-visioned.
And btw @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå, I've already changed some things on my db based on your previous tip, thanks too.